# Adding my own menu icon for navigation bar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap I have implemented a menu , which works if I set a text for the menu :

```
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = ".navbarSupportedContent">
                menuText
                //simply put here my own image
            </button>
```

I would like to insert my photo instead of `menuText`, couldn't see anyone who does that.
Can I simply add an image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `img` tag and define the `src` attribute to be the image you wish to show.

See working example below:

```css
.navbar-toggler img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarSupportedContent">
  <p>menuText</p>
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="Stackoverflow icon"/>
</button>
```

If you wish to remove "menuText" entirely and just have the image you can remove

`<p>menuText</p>`

Comment: No worries :) !!